# Numpy: from a numpy array substract 1 to each element

Tags: python, numpy

My numpy array looks like this:

```
index_up = [   71    99   103 ... 24872 24892 24928]
```

What I need:

```
index_up = [   70    98   102 ... 24871 24891 24927]
```

I tried that:

```
for e in index_up:
    e = e-1
    index_up[e] = e
```

But did not work (`index out of bounds`) any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `index_up -= 1`?

Comment: @coldspeed, as simple as that! thank you

Comment: It didnt work because you are trying to set the index e to value e. You are iterating over the values and trying to use it as index (e)

Comment: You learn this in the first paragraphs of any `numpy` tutorial. Also googling "numpy subtract from each element" yields a solution very quickly. Therefore people might downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a basic operation of numpy, you can just subtract

```
index_up -= 1
```

[Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
i=0
for e in index_up:
    e = e-1
    index_up[i]=e
    i+=1
```